# why do i keep getting these errors after running "gem pristine --all"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I try to run `gem pristine --all`  and I keep getting this in the console.

when I run `gem pristine --all` I get this:

`Permission denied`....

I even tried to do `gem install` for every `gem` and still get this:

```
`Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
    Ignoring byebug-5.0.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 5.0.0
    Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
    Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
    Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
    Ignoring json-1.8.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.3
    Ignoring mysql-2.9.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql --version 2.9.1
    Ignoring mysql2-0.3.18 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.3.18
    Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
    Ignoring pg-0.18.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.18.2`
```

Answer (score 8):

Update your RVM to `> 1.26.11` or stable with:

```
rvm get stable
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3348).

Answer (score 6):

For me, it was as simple as installing Bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old case, I ran into an error like this recently and none of the solutions had helped. Here is how I fixed the issue.

I was receiving this error when running any 'gem' command:

> Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.

What I had done prior to getting this error was upgraded my ruby with rvm

> rvm upgrade 2.0.0 2.4.0

I fixed the issue by Uninstalling 2.4.0

> rvm uninstall 2.4.0

Then Reinstalling it

> rvm install 2.4.0

Problem fixed.