# Rails not working in project directory, works elsewhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running this on Ubuntu, trying to setup my laptop for when I take home over break. So I can work on this RoR app I've been doing. This is my first app I'm making with it, so somewhat new to this!

I made sure I installed the same versions of Ruby and Rails, specifically...

```
ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-linux]
```

and

```
Rails 4.2.6
```

I check the version in my terminal with both my desktop and laptop and it's the same.

When I cloned my project directory to my laptop from github, go into the directory and run "rails -v" to check the version, I get....

```
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/carson/Programs/shiplist/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I installed the gem (gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2) like it said, but I get the same thing still.

I also tried [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726848/why-do-i-keep-getting-these-errors-after-running-gem-pristine-all), running...

```
rvm get stable
```

But it also did not work.

**EDIT** I followed [this guide to install both Ruby and Ruby on Rails](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04) with my laptop. I used the rvm method for Ruby but may have used a different method on my desktop, if that makes a difference.

**EDIT** Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile` here?

Comment: Just edited the OP with it!

Comment: Try `sudo gem install bundler`

Comment: Still the same thing unfortunately after doing that.

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv? If using `rvm` please follow this link https://rvm.io/development/debugging to see if it is properly installed

Comment: Ok I'll check that thank you! I believe my laptop is using rvm but my desktop is not, running "which ruby" i get /home/carson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby on my laptop and just /usr/bin/ruby on my desktop. Would that be an issue?

Comment: Did running `gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2` and `gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7` solves the issue?

Comment: No running them did not solve it.

Comment: Are they erroring out,? if so add the error log for them also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128671/discussion-between-harshs08-and-carson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because on the laptop ruby was installed with rvm and the desktop ruby was installed with rbenv. They were conflicting with each other somehow using a project setup with rbenv way and then trying to use it with rvm.

To switch from rvm to rbenv on the laptop, go to [RVM troubleshooting](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting) and follow the section on "How do I completely clean out all traces of RVM from my system, including for system wide installs?"

Then, go back to the tutorial [here](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04) and use the rbenv and versions used on the desktop where the project was created.

This worked for me with two Ubuntu machines

Answer (score 0):

I think that you didn't install `bundler`, try to install `gem install bundler` and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

1. you don't have gem `bundler` installed
2. In your project dir there's a binstub for rails (`bin/rails` file)
3. `./bin` is in your PATH.

So when you execute `rails -v` in your project dir, your `bin/rails` runs instead of the gem executable from GEM_PATH. And `bin/rails` tries to load bundler, which is not installed. That's why you get the error.

Just install bundler.